# Elimination of arbitrary function

Tags: partial-derivative

$ F(x^2+y^2+z^2, z^2-2xy)=0 $

I checked some online examples and I started by letting

$u=x^2+y^2+z^2$, $v=z^2-2xy$

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=2x+2zp$

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=2y+2zq$

$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=z^2-2xy$

$\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=2zq-2x$

Finding Jacobian

$0= 4(x+zp)(zq-x)-4(zp-y)(y+zq)$

But I am not sure of this method and it does not give the answer.

Comment: I didn't understand the problem you are dealing with. What is $F$?

Comment: @iamvegan, F is the arbitrary function that I have to eliminate.